# Fatal error: The files has issues. Please contact your Technical Project Manager in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, linux, configuration, centos7, ioncube

I am having trouble resetting up a PHP server after it being deleted. I have double checked to make sure that ionCube was enabled on the project. But both locally and on the hosting service I am using I have ran into this error. The hosting service support did double check my [enter link description here](https://sharetext.me/yqhqigm3xn)php.ini as they technically have a user-intractable way to edit it.

> Fatal error: The files has issues. Please contact your Technical Project Manager in Unknown on line 0

What would be a possible solution or is the above error having to deal with misplaced/ missing files?

[phpinfo()](https://sharetext.me/yqhqigm3xn)

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: Unfortunately there was not a backup put in place from the handover so the only option is to redo it from step one. at least we still have the source code